# Disparador para calculo de horas pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, trigger

Buenas a todos y gracias de ante mano por el tiempo que me presteis;

Mi problema es el siguiente tengo que programar un disparador en mi base datos que calcule el exceso de horas o en su defecto las horas de menos y salte un aviso.

He puesto esto;

```
create or replace trigger horas
before insert or update
on viajes
declare
exceso_horas exception;
menos_horas exception;
HORAS NUMBER(2);
MINUTOS NUMBER(2);
TOTALMINUTOS NUMBER (4,2);
TOTAL NUMBER (4,2);
idt PARTES.TRABAJADORES_ID%type;
est partes.estado%type;
BEGIN
SELECT TRABAJADORES_ID , extract(hour from (to_timestamp((select max(horafinal) from viajes where TRABAJADORES_ID = (select trabajadores_id from partes where estado='ABIERTO')), 'HH24:MI') - to_timestamp((select min(horainicial)from viajes where TRABAJADORES_ID = (select trabajadores_id from partes where estado='ABIERTO')),  'HH24:MI'))) ,
   extract(minute from (to_timestamp((select max(horafinal) from VIAJES where TRABAJADORES_ID = (select trabajadores_id from partes where estado='ABIERTO')), 'HH24:MI') - to_timestamp((select min(HORAINICIAL)from viajes where TRABAJADORES_ID = (select trabajadores_id from partes where estado='ABIERTO') ),  'HH24:MI'))) INTO  idt, HORAS, MINUTOS
FROM VIAJES where TRABAJADORES_ID =(select trabajadores_id from partes where estado='ABIERTO') group by TRABAJADORES_ID ;
TOTALMINUTOS:=MINUTOS/100;
TOTAL:=HORAS+TOTALMINUTOS;
IF TOTAL<8 THEN
RAISE menos_horas;
else 
RAISE exceso_horas;
end if;
EXCEPTION
when menos_horas then
 RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'pocas horas');
when exceso_horas then
 RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'muchas horas');
END horas;
```

y la consecuencias es esta:

```
insert into viajes (id, horainicial, horafinal, trabajadores_id, fecha_id, albaran) values (25, '12:00','19:00',1,'10/05/2017',15)
Informe de error -
Error SQL: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
ORA-06512: at "LOGISTICA.HORAS", line 11
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'LOGISTICA.HORAS'
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Lo he probado tambien con after

```
insert into viajes (id, horainicial, horafinal, trabajadores_id, fecha_id, albaran) values (25, '12:00','19:00',1,'10/05/2017',15)
Informe de error -
Error SQL: ORA-04091: table LOGISTICA.VIAJES is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "LOGISTICA.HORAS", line 11
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'LOGISTICA.HORAS'
04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
*Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
       this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
       in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
*Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.
```

un saludo.

Comment: has intentado ejecutar tu query del select fuera del trigger y ver si te funciona?

Comment: si pongo la select de extraccion en un procidimento consigo lo que quiero. yo partes por dia solo puedo tener abierto uno y ese esta relacionado con viajes, lo que quiero es que cuando cambie el estado del parte a cerrado si el trabajador ha echo más o menos horas que se le avise. consegui que haga esto; insert into viajes (id, horainicial, horafinal, trabajadores_id, fecha_id, albaran) values (25, '12:00','13:00',1,'10/05/2017',15)
Informe de error -
Error SQL: ORA-20001: pocas horas
ORA-06512: at "LOGISTICA.HORAS", line 23
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'LOGISTICA.HORAS'

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que estás mezclando los errores y sus causas respectivas.  A continuación te doy una explicación de los 3 errores que has mencionado y sus causas.

#### single-row subquery returns more than one row

```
Error SQL: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
ORA-06512: at "LOGISTICA.HORAS", line 11
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'LOGISTICA.HORAS'
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
```

Si los detalles de tu pregunta son correctos, el error entonces debe provenir de la consulta siguiente:

```
SELECT TRABAJADORES_ID,
       extract(hour from (to_timestamp((select max(horafinal) from viajes where TRABAJADORES_ID = (select trabajadores_id from partes where estado='ABIERTO')), 'HH24:MI') 
               - to_timestamp((select min(horainicial)from viajes where TRABAJADORES_ID = (select trabajadores_id from partes where estado='ABIERTO')),  'HH24:MI'))),
       extract(minute from (to_timestamp((select max(horafinal) from VIAJES where TRABAJADORES_ID = (select trabajadores_id from partes where estado='ABIERTO')), 'HH24:MI')
               - to_timestamp((select min(HORAINICIAL)from viajes where TRABAJADORES_ID = (select trabajadores_id from partes where estado='ABIERTO') ),  'HH24:MI')))
INTO  idt, HORAS, MINUTOS
FROM VIAJES 
where TRABAJADORES_ID = (select trabajadores_id from partes where estado='ABIERTO') 
group by TRABAJADORES_ID ;
```

En este caso, la causa más probable es que tu consulta te está devolviendo más de un registro, lo que no es compatible con la sintaxis `SELECT ... INTO ...`.

#### ORA-04091: table LOGISTICA.VIAJES is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

```
Error SQL: ORA-04091: table LOGISTICA.VIAJES is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "LOGISTICA.HORAS", line 11
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'LOGISTICA.HORAS'
04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
*Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
       this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
       in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
*Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.
```

Según la pregunta, obtuvistes este error cambiando el trigger de `BEFORE` a `AFTER`. Estoy convencido que esto no es cierto.

El error *mutating trigger* se debe a que en el trigger estás tratando de leer registros de la tabla que están en curso de modificación por la sentencia `insert` o `update`. Esto es ilegal en Oracle.

Este tipo de error puede suceder si tu trigger es un *row level* (`for each row`) trigger (`before` o `after`, no importa), o si es un `before` *statement level* trigger.  Aunque no es lo que mencionastes en tu pregunta, pero estoy seguro que este error sucede cuando tu trigger lo tienes como un `before` trigger.

Una manera de evitar este problema y que debería funcionar con el diseño de tu trigger, es de modificar el trigger para que, en vez de disparar ***antes*** de la modificación, que más bien dispare ***después***.

Cambiando (`before`):

```
create or replace trigger horas
before insert or update
on viajes
```

... a (`after`):

```
create or replace trigger horas
after insert or update
on viajes
```

#### Error SQL: ORA-20001: pocas horas

En los comentarios mencionastes que también recibistes el error siguiente:

```
Informe de error - 
Error SQL: ORA-20001: pocas horas 
ORA-06512: at "LOGISTICA.HORAS", line 23 
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'LOGISTICA.HORAS'
```

Si es el caso, entonces quiere decir que tu trigger funcionó correctamente. Este error se debe a que el trigger ejecutó correctamente tu código donde especificastes que si `TOTAL<8` entonces quieres lanzar el error `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'pocas horas');`

Con esto dicho, obviamente tu lógica necesita ser revisada, porque con las líneas siguientes:

```
IF TOTAL<8 THEN
RAISE menos_horas;
else 
RAISE exceso_horas;
end if;
```

... estás garantizando que, sin importar el valor de `TOTAL`, siempre vas a lanzar un error, por lo que tu `INSERT` o `UPDATE` nunca va a tener éxito.

Comment: si lo pongo a after obtengo lo mismo

Comment: si pongo AFTER obtengo lo mismo y no me inserta la fila; insert into viajes (id, horainicial, horafinal, trabajadores_id,fecha_id,albaran) values (22,'13:00','14:00', 27, '10/05/2017', 1)
Informe de error -
Error SQL: ORA-20001: pocas horas
ORA-06512: at "LOGISTICA.HORAS", line 23
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'LOGISTICA.HORAS'

Comment: Agregué más detalles a la respuesta para ayudarte. Pero ten cuidado al examinar el error que obtienes. Creo que no te estás fijando bien cuando el error cambia y por qué razón.

Comment: Lo que pretendo hacer realmente es hacer un calculo de horas y que estas se almacene en la tabla partes. Y luego una vez validado el parte que este ponga la diferencia de horas. Aunque la verdad ya con conseguir que me calcule las horas me doy por contento. Si pongo la sentencia en un procedimiento me va guay pero si la coloco en el trigger no obtengo lo que busco. La tabla viajes como has podido observar tiene horaini y horafin esta tabla esta relacionada con partes donde cada empleado solo puede tener un parte abierto.